# How to get array index from x and y coordinates in NxN grid

Tags: coordinates

I am aware that you can get x and y coordinates from the array index using modulo and division, but is there any way we can do the opposite? (ie, get array index from x and y coordinates)

Comment: If `x` is the horizontal coordinate, then you can do `index = y * N + x`, where `N` is the width (horizontal length) of the array. The height doesn't matter.